# Can I link images in a Powerpoint to a website so when the image updates on the site it updates in my Powerpoint?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, hyperlink, automatic-update

My company uses a digital asset repository website to store and share media for use within the company. Not a public website. We make Powerpoints to train on our products. We often change packaging and labels and the corresponding Powerpoint becomes outdated. I'm looking for a solution that links the image in the Powerpoint and updates periodically. I would also be fine if there was an intermediary step between the PPT and the our website.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done on this issue?

Comment: Also, what version(s) of Powerpoint?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083041/dynamically-link-images-to-actual-files and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/powerpoint-2010-linked-image-automatic-update/af39419d-b66d-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5 are two places to start.

Comment: @music2myear  I haven't tried much, as I'm unsure where to start. I'm using PPT on a Mac version 16.25. Thanks for the two leads.

Comment: You have to start with research. Then you begin trying things. Those links both suggest similar things to try. Once you've tried those, and if you find they're not working, then you use that EDIT button to tell us the research you've done and what you've tried, and we'll have a better idea what, specifically, is causing the problems you're experiencing.

Comment: One caveat: if your asset repository requires a login, I don't think PowerPoint will be able to get past that in order to update the links. I'd love it if someone can provide a method of linking that proves me wrong, because this comes up fairly often in support forums. Go on, folks, hit me with your best shot. ;-)